# SQL join match only the largest value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, window-functions

The scenario is we have assignments and feedback given by the student after the assignment. They are not related in the database (except by course and student). There are multiples of each. A student can be retested in an assignment and can give feedback multiple times.

Take the following scenario:

ASSIGNMENT

```
Name    time (these are really Unixtimestamps)
A1  0600
A1  1800
A2  0700
```

FEEDBACK

```
Assignment  time    key
A1      0700    feedback 1
A1      1200    feedback 2
A1      1900    feedback 3
```

The student sat assignment A1 at 0600 and provided their feedback at 0700 (feedback 1). They changed their mind and updated their feedback at 1200 (feedback 2). They were then retested in assignment A1 at 1800 and provided their feedback to the restest at 1900 (feedback 3). Separately they sat A2 and didn’t provide feedback.

We need to match the feedback to the assignment based on time.

The output should be (one row per row from the assignment table)

```
Assignment  assignmenttime  feedbacktime    Feedback
A1          0600            0700            feedback 1
A1          1800            1900            feedback 3
A2          0700            NULL            NULL
```

Feedback1 relates to A1 because I can join on the name and feedback.time is greater than assignment.time. My problem is if there are multiple feedback records I just want the smallest one that is larger than the assignment time.
If there's no feedback record matching an assignment / time then we still want the assignment record.

What’s the MYSQL to make this happen?
Thanks.

Comment: To format as `code`, select the text and press `ctrl-k`  or add 4 spaces before each line

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thanks for the edit, but I now I have a another problem: I don't know how to write the query :~(

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, doesnt look easy

Comment: dbdummy what version is your MySQL?

Comment: I'm guessing you also see the problem that depending on the data, even a correlated LIMIT query might pick up on the same thing twice.  Yeah...window functions would definitely help here.

Comment: dbdummy If student A2 do another test and give feedback, how you know if the feedback is related to the first or the second test?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting. MySQL is version 8.0 community version on Windows.

Comment: Yes - there are scenarios where we cannot match exactly the feedback to the correct assignment. But this is highly unlikely in our environment. The next feedback after the assessment is fine. (Which may mean some feedback appears multiple times.)

Comment: I think it would be useful to update the data set and desired result to account for these edge cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you need the first feedback time after the submission of assignment.

Can you try the below query -

```
SELECT NAME, 
       assginment_time, 
       feedback_time, 
       col3 
FROM   (SELECT t1.NAME, 
               t1.time1               AS assginment_time, 
               t2.time1               AS feedback_time, 
               t2.col3, 
               row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   partition BY t1.NAME, t1.time1 
                   ORDER BY t2.time1) AS rnk 
        FROM   (SELECT NAME, 
                       time1, 
                       COALESCE(lead(time1) 
                                  OVER ( 
                                    partition BY NAME 
                                    ORDER BY time1), 9999) next_time 
                FROM   assignments) t1 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN feedback t2 
                            ON t1.NAME = t2.col1 
                               AND t2.time1 BETWEEN t1.time1 AND t1.next_time) A 
WHERE  A.rnk = 1;
```

Have Changed the column names, please refer to dbfiddle link - 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1eac67b052e435e055608e95668a436f

Comment: Thanks. dbfiddle is amazing and your help is much appreciated.